# Adding text in a bitmap graphic context (on macOS) with Swift

Tags: swift, macos, bitmap, core-graphics, cgcontext

My project is

1. to paste some image crops on a bitmap graphic context
2. to add some text
3. to save the bitmap as a JPEG image

I have no problem for 1) and 3) but I can’t find a way for adding text to the bitmap graphic context. I spent many hours reading some posts but without success.
The doc (https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext/1586505-showtextatpoint) says that I should consider Core Text but I have
no idea how I should use Core Text to add some text to my
bitmap context. I also read  that the draw instance method of NSString allows
to write text in the current graphic context but AFAIK the current
graphic context is not related to my bitmap graphic context ?

To be clear, I am not interested by drawing text at the screen, I am interested by drawing text in my Bitmap and to save this bitmap in a file.

```
let colorSpace:CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
// Create the bitmap graphic context
var gc = CGContext(data: nil, width: 400, height: 400, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0,
                   space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue)

// draw an image (croppedCGImage is a CGImage instance)
var rect = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width:200, height: 200)
gc?.draw(croppedCGImage, in: rect)

// draw some text ????
// how to do that ?

// make a new CGImage
let newImage = gc!.makeImage()
```

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: no one? ........

Comment: Old question, but fro the look of that, I'd start by setting `bytesPerRow` to the width of the image context, in this case 400.